# Acessing a random array a given number of times without using the random module (Python)

Tags: python

For instance, let's say I have a random array `[5,2,1,3,6,4]` and I want to access it at least 6 times (i.e. 6 == len(array)) (the acess order doesn't matter, nor does it matter that I've accessed them all). How can I randomly access the whole array without popping any of the values ?

In other words, I am trying to write a function `find_new_index` which takes an index `i` such that:

```
arr = [5,2,1,3,6,4]
i=0
x = 0
while i < 6:
    access = arr[i]
    x+=1
    i = i + find_new_index(i)
assert(x >= 6)
```

The idea is that this function works for any random array of size N which has random values from 1 to N.

PS : The easy way to write `find_index`is to generate a random number within it. However, I want to know if it's possible to write this function without loops or any function calls.

This differs from other questions, since I don't want to use the Random Module.

Comment: Are you trying to get the 6 elements in a random order, or can one element be returned multiple times?

Comment: one element can be returned multiple times. What I access really doesn't matter. What matters is how many times I access the array and the fact that I want to access it randomly

Comment: You say you want a random element, but you don't want to use the `random` module.  This is much like saying that you want to add integers, but without using the `+` operator.  If you don't use the provided facility, then you have to write your own.  In that case, research how to write a RNG (random number generator).  There is plenty of documentation on line; we expect you to do that research before posting here.

Comment: I can't write my own random generator, because as I said, I can't use any loops or function calls. This is simply an exercise that a friend of mine gave as a challenge.

Comment: Now I'm *really* confused; how does a RNG inherently require a loop or a function call?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `random.choice(my_list)` function.

```
import random
arr = [5,2,1,3,6,4]

i = 0
while i < 6:
    access = random.choice(arr)
    #do whatever you want
    i += 1
```

For example, print the `access` adding a `print(access)` instead of the comment can output something like:

```
2
2
6
6
4
1
```

Comment: lol.. i even forgot `choice` existed!, yours is a better answer...

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. Can you have another look please ? I don't want to use the random module for my function

Comment: @Kris Got it, I try to think for something else

Comment: @Kris would you be okay using the `secrets` module instead of the `random` module? He too has the `choice` method similar to the random ones

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use the random module:

```
import random
arr=[5,2,1,3,6,4]
access =[]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    access.append(arr[random.randint(0,len(arr))])
print(access)

>>> [1,2,1,4,4,6]
```

**UPDATE**

> This differs from other questions, since I don't want to use the Random Module.

the one way i think you can make it is with the time module....

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_random(mini,maxi):
    timestamp = datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000
    return timestamp % maxi + mini

# rest of the code ...    
for i in range(len(arr)):
    access.append(arr[get_random(0,len(arr))])
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Can you please have another look at my question ? I forgot to mention that I didn't want to use the random module. All I have is a random array.

Comment: changed... take a look